# Multiple paragraphs in a CQ5 page don't work

Tags: aem

I tried adding muultiple  "par" components in my template's JSP. But only the one appearing first is visible on the page.

Is there is limitation of using paragraphs in a page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the value for your path  variable

```
<cq:include path="par1" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
<cq:include path="par2" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
```

this should help you in having multiple paragraph components