# Generic component in CQ5 page

Tags: aem

My question is very basic . I am creating a new template and in that template, I will have a concrete structure using DIV elements. But in almost 7-8 if the DIV's, I need the data to be entered by the user.

What component/line of code I can use to have all those 7-8 DIV's editable and customizable by the page creator ?

I tried multiple paragraphs with :

```
<cq:include path="par" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys"/>
```

But only the top one appears on the page. !!

Comment: Does the path attribute of each cq:include differ?

Comment: @diffa .. looks like I was using the same value for 'path' attribute in all instances... So stupid of me !!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For having multiple paragraph just rename the path value in the cq:include tag. also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14997145/2094081)