# Adobe CQ: Make two <cq:include> with same path editable

Tags: adobe, aem

I have two `"cq:include"` in same jsp with same path and I need to make both of them editable. But currently only one of them is editable.

If I change anything in one component that shows on second. But the second one itself is not editable. My requirement is to make both the components editable while keeping the include path same.

*Code:*

```
<cq:include path ="abc" resourceType="xyz"/>
<cq:include path ="abc" resourceType="xyz"/> # This one is not editable.
```

Comment: added both components in in Question!

Comment: I honestly think this isn't possible. The JavaScript needs one DIV as the reference for the overlay. So it probably makes the first one it finds in the DOM editable and ignores the second because the path is the same.

Comment: @Thomas: :( Yeah this could be the case. Lets try a little with some more answers. Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the authoring system works it hooks per location so if you want to have it authored in two different places those two different places should NOT be on the same page.  This is just good usability as it can be very confusing.

INSTEAD, I suggest the first one on the page add an attribute to the slingRequest noting that it has been placed on the page and future instances with the same path put a message on the screen saying that it is edited elsewhere.  Without knowing more details it's hard to suggest the best usability for this scenario.

Update:
If you MUST do this, here is a work around.
Step 1: define a convention for naming 2 properties.  e.g. realTitle (String) and realTitleLastUpdated (date/time).  These will be page-level properties, making it easy to access and check them using pageProperties.  Though you can do this through a subnode as well but that gets more complicated.

Step 2: For the components that must all be simulateously editable, allow them to create their own nodes.  Then, on load in the EDIT environment, check the property realTitle and the lastUpdated time stored in realTitleLastUpdated

If the last edit of your component's title, e.g. jcr:lastModified is newer than realTitleLastUpdated, change the local value of title (e.g. jcr:title) to the value of the realTitle property and update the realTitleLastUpdated time to reflect the time in jcr:lastModified on your component.

If the opposite is true - realTitleLastUpdated is of a time newer than the last modification of the local component, then update the jcr:title of the component and the times to match.

Obviously if the last update times match, do nothing.

It's a bit of a run around, but this will keep everything in sync.

I realized that you may not realize that you probably need to save the state.  I believe you can do this (among other ways) using resource.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class).save()

I've done this before but it's been a while.  Let me know if you have issues, I'm working from memory.

Comment: Scenario is: I have this ("say title") component in a page at two places. Then there is one rte below each title component. The content in the RTEs will be served dynamically but the title remains same in both the cases. Now problem here is: author can choose to edit any one of title components and the text thus entered in any of the title component should reflect in both. That's why I need both the components editable while keeping the include path same. Moreover this also need to work in NO JS mode. So can't use js triggers. Please suggest--

Comment: @aneeshsharma I still think this is bad usability but I also recognize that sometimes you just don't have a choice due to business edicts.

I'll reply as a separate thread, I'll run out of room here.

Comment: @aneeshsharma I've updated my answer to describe a work around.  Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 1):

Having two components with the same resource type would create only a single node at the given path. Hence, any change you make in one of the component would be reflecting in both of them, as both the components would be reading from the same node.

This is also the reason for not being able to edit the second component. Try providing different paths for different components like shown below.

```
<cq:include path="abc" resourceType="xyz" />
<cq:include path="abc_0" resourceType="xyz" />
```

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995633/multiple-paragraphs-in-a-cq5-page-dont-work) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995644/generic-component-in-cq5-page)

Comment: Hi @rakhi4110,My Basic need is to make both the components editable while keeping the include path same. Please suggest a way around.

Comment: @aneeshsharma Y do you want to keep the include path same. As i said, keeping the path same means having a single config for both of them.

Comment: My requirement is to make both the include paths same so that any change in one reflects on other. But at the same time, author can choose to edit any one of these. So need to make both the components editable. It works great with different paths but then author need to edit the same thing at two places. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't want author to bother about editing both the components, then you should use javascript/jquery and `onChange()` of one of the component, modify the value of another component as well.

Comment: This would be bad practice.  The UI is usually done in Ext.js so you'd be running onChange handlers on things updated by a different JS framework.  That's a long run around.  In addition, that change would have to be persisted to the JCR to work properly, which would mean knowing the node name/location of all linked components ahead of time to send appropriate JSON posts to those node locations.  Doing this would be a LOT of extra work, or you would write a servlet to accept that update and hook into one of the Ext.js events to send to that servlet but that's still somewhat overkill.